# Best method of sharing classes between node server and browser frontend? (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm just getting into client/server architecture and am not sure if there is a best practice for this. I have a file structure as follows:

```
.
|-public
|  |-index.html
|  |-client.js
|  |-src
|  |  |-person.js
|-server.js
```

person.js is a class that I would like to share between the server and the client. socket.io lets me send over a json object, but I cannot find a way to send methods attached to a Person(). So instead, I'm resorting to sending over a json and reinitializing the Person object. This also leads me to some import issues.

On server.js:

```
const { Person } = require('./public/src/person')
...

io.on('connection', client => client.emit('init', new Person({data}))
```

On client.js:

```
let person;
socket.on('init', handlePerson);
function handlePerson(data) {
    person = new Person(data);
    person.method();
    ...
}
```

While this works, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. It's also forcing me to put an ugly export at the bottom of person.js:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = {
        Overworld
    }
}
```

where the server requires the inner module.exports, but the client would get
`Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`

I should add, my index.html is importing the js files like so:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/src/Overworld.js"></script>
<script src="/client.js"></script>
```

I think one of these files must be seriously cringe for an experienced js developer. Any help or explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: you really shouldn't be sending objects which have methods on them anyway, if Person is simple and does not have any dependencys you could load the file as a string, don't invoke it, send it as a string and eval it.. see not a good idea. pass data not instances of objects

Comment: "*sending over a json and reinitializing the Person object*" - yes, you cannot avoid that. Methods are not serialisable. JSON is a good and totally standard format.

Comment: "*person.js is a class that I would like to share between the server and the client.*" - are you using any sort of build tooling?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies guys!

"you really shouldn't be sending objects which have methods on them anyway"
- my plan later on is to send many game objects over, then to send change events (player move right 5 px), and for the client side to run the event through the classes that are reinitialized. So they have to share these methods for the server/client to process these events similarly

Comment: "are you using any sort of build tooling? – 
Bergi
 "
I'm not exactly sure what build tooling is? I'm using npm and express.

Comment: Modern web allows you to use modules in the browser. Load the script with `type="module"` and then you can use `import { Person } from 'file/path`. Also read about bundlers.